# php image crop by cordinates

Tags: php, crop

I have image info with all coordinates. I need to crop image exactly selected section.

I have created a c custom function in wordpress and pass all required fields. this code crop the image but not provided exactly output.

Here imageId is attachement id of image in wordpress

```
 <?php 
      $ft_data = array(
                  "img_w" => 600,
                  "img_h" => 449.94375703037,
                  "w" => 120,
                  "h" => 80,
                  "s" => 100,
                  "x" => 42,
                  "y" => 0
                );

    $crop_coords => array(
                        "x" => 105,
                        "y" => 0,
                        "x2" => 405,
                        "y2" => 200,
                        "w" => 300,
                        "h" => 200
                    );
);
```

$imageId = 101;

```
       function imageCrop($ft_data , $crop_coords , $imageId){
       $json_string = stripslashes($ft_data);
        $data = json_decode($json_string, true);

        $x1     = $data['x'];
        $y1     = $data['y'];
        $width  = $data['w'];
        $height = $data['h'];



        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $imageId );

        $info = pathinfo($image_url);

        // get the filename without the extension
        $image_name =  basename($image_url,'.'.$info['extension']);

        // get the extension without the image name
        $ext    = end(explode('.', $image_url));
        $im     = imagecreatefromfile($image_url);
        $size   = min(imagesx($im), imagesy($im));

        $to_crop_array = array('x' =>$x1 , 'y' => $y1, 'width' => $width, 'height'=> $height );

        $im2    = imagecrop($im, $to_crop_array );

        if ($im2 !== FALSE) {


          $NewImg = $image_name ."-new".date('d-m-y-H-i-s',time())."." . $ext;
          $upload_dir   = wp_upload_dir();

          $savePath = $upload_dir['path']."/".$NewImg;
          echo $newImgUrl = $upload_dir['url']."/".$NewImg;
            session_start();
          $_SESSION["cropedImage"] = $newImgUrl;
          // setcookie('cropedImage', $newImgUrl, time()+3600);
          // WC()->session->set( 'cropedImage', $newImgUrl);

          $res = imagepng($im2, $savePath );
          imagedestroy($im2); 
          die;
        }
          imagedestroy($im);
       }

?>
```

I have image info with all coordinates. I need to crop image exactly selected section.

I have a custom function and pass all required fields. this code crop the image but not provided exactly output

Comment: I need to crop image using php.

Comment: Your question needs clarification. You need to tell us what your code actually does, and then what you want it to do. Also make sure your code is valid. Please remember that if we cannot run your code, if it contains bugs, if we don't have the image, and if you don't tell us what you want, then we cannot help you.

Comment: Please put any clarifications in your question, not in a comment. That way new readers of your question will see it when they read the question.

Comment: added some more infomations